# Loading Raid drivers during Proxmox VE installation

Tags: debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openvz, proxmox

I'm using Hardware raid on my Proxmox VE installation and it doesn't recognize my Raid array, so how can I load raid drivers during installation?

This is the driver reseller provided: ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/driver/SATA/Adaptec_ICH10R/Linux/17725.2/17725.2.zip

Website: http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/qpi/5500/x8da3.cfm

Regards.

Comment: You have two RAID items on that motherboard: The `LSI 1068E 8-Port SAS Controller;  RAID 0, 1, 10; RAID 5 optional.`  This is the hardware RAID which you want to use. And `6x SATA2 (3 Gbps) Ports via ICH10R Controller`. The ICH10R has software RAID. This is **not** the one you want. But the reseller link you provided leads to a drivers for the fake-RAID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two RAID items on that motherboard:

1. The LSI 1068E 8-Port SAS Controller; RAID 0, 1, 10; RAID 5 optional.
   This is the hardware RAID which you want to use.
2. 6x SATA2 (3 Gbps) Ports via ICH10R Controller.
   The ICH10R has software RAID. This is not the one you want.

The reseller link you provided leads to a drivers for the fake-RAID.

The other link you provided lead to the motherboard and its manual.
From the motherboard manual, page 2-35:

> In addition to SATA connections an LSI 1068E SAS controller and eight SAS connectors are located on the X8DA3. To configure LSI SAS RAID  settings, please refer to the LSI SAS RAID user guide posted on our website http://www.supermicro/com/manuals/

I think they are referring to the `LSI MegaRAID_Configuration_for_the_LSI_1068_Controller.pdf`

Quoting from that:

> After you have installed hardware components, you must first configure the LSI MegaRAID Software Utility before you install an operating system and other soft-ware drivers.

And a bit further:

> To Activate RAID Modes
>   You can activate a RAID mode by pressing any key in the BIOS setup.
>   Press CTRL + C to activate the IT mode.
>   Press CTRL + M to activate the SR mode.

Do this first, then check if Debian needs any additional drivers for this SAS chip.
(I expect it to work out of the box because the 1068E is a few years old and support for ti seem to be quite common. But it never hurts to check.)

Comment: Really Thanks for you help Hennes, I'll check and report back.

Comment: I checked this but it doesn't still recognize raid arrays. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: 0) Did you create the array with Control-C or control-M?  1) Which proxmod are you using? if it is version 2.1 then please see http://forum.proxmox.com/archive/index.php/t-9754.html  2) Do you get any message similar to `Fusion MPT SAS` while booting (either on screen or in your dmesg)  3) Else can you boot and do a `lspci` to determine the correct driver?

Comment: Thank you Hennes, I'm using Proxmox version 2.2 and even VMware ESX 5 can't recognize Raid arrays But Windows Server 2008 R2 can. Let me try again what you mentioned.